# Ajax request does not work on a cascading dropdown value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Hi I have a cascading drop-down and on it's change I have a requirement to populate another field by getting it's value from the database.

unfortunately when I try to populate the drop-down my ajax always responds an error 500. I don't know what is wrong with it.

I am using this [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sourabh_mishra1/cascading-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) as my guide.

Here is my **Javascript**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#selectedExperience_ExpertiseID').change(function () {
        var selectedExpertise = $('#selectedExperience_ExpertiseID :selected').val();
        selectedExpertise = selectedExpertise == "" ? 0 : selectedExpertise;
        //When select 'optionLabel' we need to reset it to default as well. So not need
        //travel back to server.
        if (selectedExpertise == "") {
            $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').empty();
            $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').append('<option value="">--Select a language--</option>');
            return;
        }

        //This is where the dropdownlist cascading main function
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "GetFunctionByID", //Your Action name in the DropDownListConstroller.cs
            async: false,
            data: { selectedExpertise: selectedExpertise },  //Parameter in this function, Is cast sensitive and also type must be string
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"

        }).done(function (data) {
            //When succeed get data from server construct the dropdownlist here.
            if (data != null) {

                $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').empty();
                $.each(data.function, function (index, data) {
                    $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').append('<option value="' + data.Value + '">' + data.Text + '</option>');
                });
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            if (response.status != 0) {
                alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and here is my **HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedExperience.ExpertiseID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedExperience.ExpertiseID, Model.expertise, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedExperience.ExpertiseID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.selectedExperience.FunctionID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedExperience.FunctionID, Model.function, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedExperience.FunctionID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please help me. I am stuck in this functionality for 4 days now.

point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: try using :
`url: "page.aspx/methodname",`
`data: '{jsonname: "' + jsonvalue + '}','`

Comment: url: "/DropDownList/GetDistrict", Also put the code GetFunctionByID()  into try/catch block.see what error is thrown in catch

Comment: where is this variable named  "selectedExperience_ExpertiseID" in whole html

Answer (score 0):

i think your ajax is not sending any data because of this

**data: { selectedExpertise: selectedExpertise }**
change it to 
 **data: { 'selectedExpertise': selectedExpertise }**
i think there should be a quote around the object name

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. unfortunately it still responds to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , give id to both the dropdownlists,I didnt find **selectedExperience_ExpertiseID**  and check the $.each function result 
Also,I have modified bit of html. Kindly try this code. Hope your method **GetFunctionByID** is working well.*I have take table and its column according to my reference db.*

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#selectedExperience_ExpertiseID').change(function () {
            var selectedExpertise = $('#selectedExperience_ExpertiseID :selected').val();
      
            selectedExpertise = selectedExpertise == "" ? 0 : selectedExpertise;
            //When select 'optionLabel' we need to reset it to default as well. So not need
            //travel back to server.
            if (selectedExpertise == "") {
                $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').empty();
                $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').append('<option value="">--Select a language--</option>');
                return;
            }

            //This is where the dropdownlist cascading main function
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/DropDownList/GetFunctionByID", //Your Action name in the DropDownListConstroller.cs
                async: false,
                data: { stateId: selectedExpertise },  //Parameter in this function, Is cast sensitive and also type must be string
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"

            }).done(function (data) {
                //When succeed get data from server construct the dropdownlist here.
                if (data != null) {
                  
                  
                    $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                        $('#selectedExperience_FunctionID').append('<option value="' + val.value + '">' + val.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                   
                }
            }).fail(function (response) {
                if (response.status != 0) {
                    alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
 
</script>
```

```html
@model WebApplication6.Models.StudentModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Expertise", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateNames, Model.StateNames, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "selectedExperience_ExpertiseID" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateNames, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Function", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DistrictNames, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "selectedExperience_FunctionID" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistrictNames, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```